# Given a OSM node id, how do I find the previous x points in all directions?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have a OSM node Id/ latitude-longitude for a point in the road(say point Z). How do I find the previous x points that I need to travel to reach Z in all directions? I was thinking overpass API could help me. But it is able to return points only with tags. I am not able to get it return the node Ids on the road/way.

Can you please suggest any API/tutorial that could help?

Answer (score 1):

if i'm not wrong what you are asking is: given a osm node id with coordinate x and y what are all points to do in order to arrive there from a starting point?
if this is the question well this is a graph oriented question; you should create a grah and then use some algorithm in order to find all the routes between starting point and end point; you should use some graph oriented software.. something like neo4j and spatial contrib (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial)
In past i built a project where i read an osmfile, create a graph and used A* algorithm; you may give to it a look https://github.com/angeloimm/neo4jAstarTest

Comment: Thank you Angelo. I don't have a starting point in this case. I have a ending point but I need to find few previous points from the ending point. did you get OSM file for complete city and loaded to graph before working on it?

Comment: Yes i downloaded the OSM file and loaded in neo4j

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if the order of node IDs in OSM file is the order of node IDs in the road as well? Does it maintain same order?

Comment: No, the order is completely different. This wouldn't work since a node can be part of multiple ways.

Comment: I agree with @scai

Comment: Is there any other way I can find the order of the node IDs in a way?

Comment: Using neo4j you can have the shortest paths to arrive to the final point; in the shortest path results you have all the information about the involved node (note that in this case the node id is the id inside neo4j; you must access to the node and get the osm node id)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to get started by reading about [OSM elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements), especially nodes and ways. Afterwards take a look at [OSM XML format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML). It might also help to open an OSM editor (e.g. [iD](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ID)) and to take a look at the raw data.

Nodes don't have any order or "next node" themselves. Nodes *can* be part of one or multiple ways. Each way references a list of ordered nodes. So you have to look at *all* ways a node belongs to, then look at the way's node list to determine the previous and next nodes. If the node is at the start or end of a way then you have to look if there are one or more consecutive ways. Consecutive ways share the same node at their start/end.

Comment: Thank you scai. My question was also to know if every way is list of ordered nodes. I checked couple of them. It looked like the nodes are ordered in a way. I wanted to make sure. Do you know what is the best technology I can use to parse this huge data? Hadoop will not work as I have a single XML file and there are many interdependencies.

Comment: Yes, a way references all of its nodes in the correct order. Otherwise it would be impossible to reconstruct the way geometry.

However OSM XML is not suitable for such queries. You should import the data into a spatial database.